# How to determine if type is a base class of an abstract class

Tags: c#

To check if my type was the interface type I was using the following method

```
dllFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll");

ICollection<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(dllFileNames.Length);
foreach (string dllFile in dllFileNames)
{
    AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllFile);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(an);
    assemblies.Add(assembly);
}

Type pluginType = typeof(T);
foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
{
    if (assembly != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (type.GetInterface(pluginType.FullName) != null && typeof(IBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                    {
                        pluginTypes.Add(type);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

However `IsAssignableFrom` is false now that I changed `IBase` to an abstract class.

How do I do the same thing but for a base type of an abstract class?

**EDIT:**
Yes my class inherits from the abstract class for sure

```
public class MyType : IBase{  ...   }
```

where

IBase is now

```
public abstract class IBase{   ...   }
```

and before it used to be

```
public interface IBase{ ...  }
```

**EDIT2**: unfortunately I could not recreate the issue with the following code, (both results are true)

```
    public abstract class IBlah
    {
        string test { get; set; }
    }

    public class implementation1 : IBlah
    {
    }

    public interface IBlech
    {
        string test { get; set; }
    }

    public class implementation2 : IBlech
    {
        public string test
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            bool result1 = (typeof(IBlah).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(implementation1)));
            bool result2 = (typeof(IBlech).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(implementation2)));
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do your classes actually inherit from the abstract class? show a example call of this function with a example class that fails

Comment: Could you create a simple complete example that shows the behavior you are seeing that we could just copy and paste in to our own editors and run?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's really hard to do here you know, I'm reading DLL files from disk and examining their types.

Comment: So, the types in question that you want to add to `pluginTypes` both implement `IReport` or `IProcess` *and* derive from your new abstract base, `IBase`?

Comment: Yes, but your example code could simply example `GetExecutingAssembly()`.

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly but regardless of IBase is an interface or abstract class you can do `MyType o = new MyType();

            if (o is IBase)
                Console.WriteLine("o inherits from IBase");` and it should print this text in console

Answer (score 0):

Use `type.IsSubClassOf(typeof(IBase))`

[Documentation of IsSubClassOf on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx).